# Manage multiple states in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state

I'm working in a tennis application and I'm having problem to manage a lot of states. I will explain: First round of a tournament tennis has 128 players like this, where we have for each row the player and the seed.

[image]
[image]

Array.from(Array(128)).map((p, index) => {

```
const oddIndex = index * 2 + 1
  const evenIndex = index * 2 + 2

  const getCurrentSeed = (position) => {
    const seed = !objectIsEmpty(games) && games?.rounds[round.round]?.positions[position]?.seed

    return seed || ''
  }

  const getCurrentATPPlayer = (position) => {
    const ATPPlayer = !objectIsEmpty(games) && games?.rounds[round.round]?.positions[position]?.atp_player
    return ATPPlayer || {}
  }

<div className="player">
 <ATPPlayerFinderWrapper position={oddIndex} setATPPlayerId={setATPPlayerId} setCurrentPosition={setCurrentPosition} ATPPlayer={getCurrentATPPlayer(oddIndex)} />
</div>
<div className="seed">
    <TextField
      id={`seed${oddIndex}`}
      label="Seed"
      variant="standard"
      onChange={(e) => setSeed(e.target.value)}
      InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
      value={getCurrentSeed(oddIndex)}
   />
</div>
```

});

My big problem is when I got the rows from the back, I need states for each textfield but it's not working and could be a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, take your array in a state and set each of its value to `''`.

```
const [seeds, setSeeds] = useState(Array(128).fill(''));
const [ATPPlayers, setATPPlayers] = useState(Array(128).fill({}));
```

Then whenever the state changed set its value

```
const handleSeedChange = (position, value) => {
    const newSeeds = [...seeds];
    newSeeds[position] = value;
    setSeeds(newSeeds);
  };

  const handleATPPlayerChange = (position, player) => {
    const newATPPlayers = [...ATPPlayers];
    newATPPlayers[position] = player;
    setATPPlayers(newATPPlayers);
  };
```

Here it the full code according to your problem.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TennisBracket = ({ games, round }) => {
  const [seeds, setSeeds] = useState(Array(128).fill(''));
  const [ATPPlayers, setATPPlayers] = useState(Array(128).fill({}));

  const getCurrentSeed = (position) => seeds[position] || '';

  const getCurrentATPPlayer = (position) => ATPPlayers[position] || {};

  const handleSeedChange = (position, value) => {
    const newSeeds = [...seeds];
    newSeeds[position] = value;
    setSeeds(newSeeds);
  };

  const handleATPPlayerChange = (position, player) => {
    const newATPPlayers = [...ATPPlayers];
    newATPPlayers[position] = player;
    setATPPlayers(newATPPlayers);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from(Array(128)).map((p, index) => {
        const oddIndex = index * 2 + 1;

        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div className="player">
              {/* Use your ATPPlayerFinderWrapper or any other component */}
              {/* Assuming it has a callback to pass the selected player to the parent */}
              <ATPPlayerFinderWrapper
                position={oddIndex}
                setATPPlayerId={setATPPlayerId}
                setCurrentPosition={setCurrentPosition}
                ATPPlayer={getCurrentATPPlayer(oddIndex)}
                onPlayerChange={(player) => handleATPPlayerChange(oddIndex, player)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="seed">
              <TextField
                id={`seed${oddIndex}`}
                label="Seed"
                variant="standard"
                onChange={(e) => handleSeedChange(oddIndex, e.target.value)}
                InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
                value={getCurrentSeed(oddIndex)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Great, let me understand and implement.